# Does Bitcoin have any technical advantages over Monero?

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison

Having a far larger network hashrate makes Bitcoin much more resistant to 51% attacks than Monero. Bitcoin also has the advantage of being accepted at many more merchants than Monero (when the purchased item is over the xmr.to and Shapeshift transaction limits).

Ignoring the greater expense to launch a 51% attack, are there any other technical or unique feature advantages Bitcoin has over Monero?

How does Bitcoin price volatility compare to Monero? Can lower relative volatility be considered a technical advantage for a currency that is often help for a period of time before being spent.

Would a privacy focused user of both Bitcoin and Monero wanting to purchase an item costing 2BTC or less from a BTC merchant have any reason to pay with Bitcoin instead of Monero (other than for the purposes of saving the exchange fee charged by xmr.to)?

Can the Bitcoin protect the privacy anything that Monero cannot with regard to transaction or metadata?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the primary differences between Monero and Bitcoin?](http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/415/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-monero-and-bitcoin)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be fundamentally confused over the nature of majority attacks against blockchain-based systems and privacy in general.

[Majority attacks](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Majority_attack) are not about privacy, they are about the technical ability to control what gets written to the blockchain, or ledger for the cryptocurrency. Someone in control of a majority of miners could prevent new transactions from being written, or write the transactions they want, such as spending their bitcoins multiple times. However, this is an integrity issue, not a privacy issue.

The privacy issue with BitCoin (and, to be fair, most other cryptocurrencies) is that all transactions are publicly stored in the ledger, which is unrelated to majority attacks.  This is a function of the design of these systems, in order to prevent against spending the same unit of cryptocurrency multiple times. Recording the movement of each unit of cryptocurrency in every block, prevents cryptocurrency from being spent more than once, but it also has the effect of making transactions a matter of public record, with of course, provides no privacy.  Each new block contains which accounts sent/received cryptocurrency to/from which other accounts.

Monero is different by design, in that the movement of cryptocurrency is cryptographically protected.  This is the privacy difference between Monero and other cryptocurrency systems.  Other cryptocurrency systems record transactions in the public ledger/blockchain to prevent spending the same unit of cryptocurrency more than once, where as Monero uses [ring signatures](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/ringsignatures) in processing transactions, which provides privacy, in that there is no way to be sure which of the multiple signatories to a transaction actually performed the transaction in question.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin does not have privacy advantages over Monero.

Monero is fungible and anonymous.

Bitcoin has ASIC miners, so what.. Wait until Monero has ASICs ;)

Answer (score 2):

Note: the question originally asked about Bitcoin *privacy* advantages.

- Bitcoin core can connect to the bitcoin network via a Tor hidden service.
- The vast (compared to Monero) amount of users mean that someone who is very good at not reusing addresses *may* be able to keep hidden in a large crowd, though that one is a bit grasping at straws.

You'll have to be more explicit about what you mean by implications of 51% attacks on privacy, I can't see what you mean there.