# What are advantages and disadvantages of Monero's privacy features as compared to Bitcoin?

Tags: privacy, ring-signatures, monero-forks, bitcoin, untraceability

What are the advantages and disadvantages of Monero's privacy features as compared to Bitcoin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say. The primary difference, privacy wise, is. Monero got it, and Bitcoin don't.

[What are the primary differences between Monero and Bitcoin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/415/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-monero-and-bitcoin?rq=1)
[What advantages does Monero offer that are not provided by other cryptocurrencies](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/what-advantages-does-monero-offer-that-are-not-provided-by-other-cryptocurrencie?rq=1)
[Does Bitcoin have any technical advantages over Monero](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/820/does-bitcoin-have-any-technical-advantages-over-monero)